# visual studio preview to the side missing

Tags: visual-studio-code

In this tutorial I'm following the instructor has the option to open preview to the side but I don't see it in my visual studio window, could it be removed in the new update?

to clarify my question is how do I preview my code to the side?

I'm looking to get a visualization of a decision tree

[image]

Comment: Can't seem to find any info on this online

Comment: Could You be more specific ?  Screen shot  ? ;-)

Comment: Just added a screen shot of the video tutorial, the arrow is pointing at what is missing on my screen

Comment: This is Visual Studio Code or VS Code for short. Don't misuse the other tag, which belongs to Visual Studio for Windows.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the Tip Lex Li, was very helpful in answering my question, there are new users on here too, mistakes happen.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in 3 Steps:

1. Uninstall extension: Graphviz (dot) language support for Visual Studio Code, by Stephanvs.
2. Install Graphviz Interactive Preview, by tintinweb.
3. Click Button DOT, as shown in the image, and Voila.

Have a nice day.

[Graphviz Interactive preview, by tintinweb][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZrDt.jpg

[Clich Button DOT][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkiqk.jpg

[Here is the Visualizacion][3]
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UEvN.jpg